# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _pcap_lookupdev

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

I have installed bettercap on Macbook Pro OSX EL Capitan 10.11.3, after installing while I start bettercap it shows below error.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _pcap_lookupdev
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pcaprub-0.12.1/lib/pcaprub_c.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _pcap_lookupdev
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pcaprub-0.12.1/lib/pcaprub_c.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5B3B.png]

Comment: So it looks like `libpcap` is not installed on the system.

Answer (score -2):

me too, but libpcap is installed on the system.

/usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib

/usr/lib/libpcap.dylib

also pcaprub with gem is installed and is who that give us this error.